# How to update a folder in an Azure AppService upon Checkin into a VSO TFS repository

Tags: azure, web-applications, deployment, build, azure-devops

I have a website hosted as an azure web app. It's an asp.net website that's in a vs solution. On folder of that website is my products documentation, all of it as static resources (html and images). These static resources are located in a folder in *another* vs solution (this is the actual products solution). Both solutions are TFS based in VSO.

As of now, i have a webjob running in the context of the website that is basically doing a "tfs get" on the documentation folder and placing it's contents into the documentation folder on the website. This is working, however, the vms the website is running on do change quite frequently and the mechanism to create a workspace is bound to the machine, not to the disk drive. Thus, i cannot get only the changes but i must always get all the content which right now takes about 20 minutes and creates unnecessary load on the website. (This is why i'm only running this webjob once a week.)

Now i'm looking for a better way to do this. I would like to only get the files that have changed, making this a lot faster and let cpu/drive costly.

I did not find a way to create a workspace on the webserver that isn't vanishing each time the webservers vm changes. (if it was possible to somehow attach the workspace to the drive instead of to the machine name, that would solve the problem.)

i was also looking at my continues build definition that i have running for the products solution. as part of that, i think it's possibly to create a deployment where the documentation folder is copied to the app services's documentation folder. This way i could get rid of the "special" webjob, but i'd still copy all the docs files each time. (also, the build agent for that is running on premises, so i'd also have to copy those files from premises up to the cloud when they're actually already there inside vso.). So basically, i don't think this option is a lot of use for my case.

Obviously if i moved the static docs resources from the products solution to the websites solution, i could simply use the automatic deployment that is available for website projects from vso to azure web app. Unfortunately, for various other reasons (one of which being, the static resources are partially created automatically from the .cs sources in the products solution) i simply cannot move the docs folder from the products solution to the websites solution.

So does anybody have a suggestion for a method where i could update the documentation folder in the web app based on changes in the corresponding VSO folder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what i ended up doing:

- Created a ServiceHook in VSO that is wired to "Web Hooks". The hook is called upon each Check-In and filtered based on the directory i want. (All of this can be done using the existing functionality in VSO.)
- The hook calls an Azure "functionapp" (which is easy to do, because functionapps have a "HttpTrigger" mechanism which fits in nicely here.)
- The hook passes the id of the checkins ChangeSet to the function app.
- The FunctionApp puts that id into an Azure (Storage) Queue.
- This triggers an azure webjob which listens on that queue. That webjob uses the ChangeSet-Id to get the changes from VSO and acts on the changetype for each change. (e.g.: Downloads or deletes a file.)

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the updated files to Azure app service by using Kudu API.
Simple steps:

1. Create a Continuous Integration build
2. Check Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token option in Options tab
3. Add PowerShell step/task to [check the changes with REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#with-changes). (Refer to [Calling VSTS APIs with PowerShell](http://blog.devmatter.com/calling-vsts-apis-with-powershell/))
4. Add Azure PowerShell step/task to upload files to app service by using kudu api. (Refer to [Remove files and folders on Azure before a new deploy from VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801618/remove-files-and-foldes-on-azure-before-a-new-deploy-from-vsts/43839007#43839007))