# Manage Custom App Offline via VSTS publish in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

### I want to manage a custom App offline file whilst doing a publish to azure via the Deploy Azure App Service task.

I realise that this task has a property of:`take app offline`

however this property will use the basic app offline file which is what I would like to avoid.

---

I figure I need to do something like this.

**Option 1**

1. rename file on azure service `_App_Offline.htm` to `App_offline.htm`
2. publish app.
3. rename file on azure service `App_Offline.htm` to `_App_Offline.htm`

however I can't figure out how to do steps 1 or 3.

**Option 2**

1. publish file on azure service `App_Offline.htm`
2. publish app.
3. delete file on azure service `App_Offline.htm`

I can manage steps 1 and 2 of these but how would i do step 3?

any other options i could try?

Comment: Do you solve this issue? What's the result of my solution?

Comment: I'm sure your solution is a correct approach, I just can't get it to work for some reason

Comment: What's the problem? You can share the build/release log files on the OneDrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Create/Delete/Rename file on azure app service through [kudu REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API), refer to this thread below to get more information about how to use kudu REST API during the build/release.

[Remove files and foldes on Azure before a new deploy from VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801618/remove-files-and-foldes-on-azure-before-a-new-deploy-from-vsts/43839007#43839007)

Comment: this looks promising, it would be great to have an example tho.

Comment: @ChrisWarnes Check the related thread (Remove files and folders ...), there are detail steps and sample script.