# Using VSTS can I install extensions other than those listed in the dropdown?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-build-task

I would like to install a Web App extension as part of my VSTS build/deployment. The list of options only includes a few options (mostly Python). How/can I install other extensions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in Azure App Service Manage task is static and you just can select them, but you can refer to the source code: [AzureAppServiceManage](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureAppServiceManage) to [custom build/release task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task) to include the extensions that you want.

You also could install necessary extensions through [kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#siteextensions):

> SiteExtensions
>
> GET /api/extensionfeed List all extension package infos available on
>   the online (remote) server.  The following query strings are
>   supported.
>   - filter: matching string
>
> GET /api/siteextensions List all extension package infos currently
>   installed.  The following query strings are supported.
>   - filter: matching string
>
> GET /api/extensionfeed/{id} Get a package info with {id} from remote
>   store.
>
> GET /api/siteextensions/{id} Get a package info with {id} currently
>   installed.
>
> PUT /api/siteextensions/{id} Install or update the package to local
>   machine. The payload is the package info returned by List/Get apis
>   above.
>
> DELETE /api/siteextensions/{id} Uninstall the package with {id}.

An article about [Install Azure App Extension With Powershell](http://poshdb.com/home/install-azure-app-extension-powershell/).

There is a thread to call Kudu API that can help you: [Remove files and foldes on Azure before a new deploy from VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801618/remove-files-and-foldes-on-azure-before-a-new-deploy-from-vsts/43839007)

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell\arm templates\rest call to do that. Those are not native steps, so they would require research.

Several examples:

http://wp.sjkp.dk/install-azure-site-extensions-with-arm-template/
https://gist.github.com/sethreidnz/aa996f91339bafdfb5ecb1d4681ba26c/
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-arm-with-msdeploy-provision.md

Comment: Thanks, that's a shame. I wonder why they chose to limit the options in the built-in task.