# VSTS Azure web deployment composer, php artisan

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, kudu

I am using VSTS and that is where my repository with my Laravel web application is. So I am deploying automatically to Azure.

But in order for my Application to get deployed fully automatically, I need to add a Task to VSTS that can run something in the Kudu Console. How can I implement that?

Comment: Could you ask us what you want to do in the Kudu Console? Maybe it will better help you solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergiibomko.vsts-kudu-tasks) will help.

Comment: I need to use the Kudu Console for composer install and especially for php artisan.

Comment: The Link doesn't help me, because it seems that it only can upload stuff to kudu

Comment: What's the result after trying it with Kudu API?

Answer (score 0):

Using Kudu REST API.

There is a thread about how to use Kudu REST API in build/release:

[Remove files and foldes on Azure before a new deploy from VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801618/remove-files-and-foldes-on-azure-before-a-new-deploy-from-vsts/43839007#43839007)

Comment: Thank you for the Link, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, as i can only delete/upload or get files via the API and can't execute a command in the console.

The command also works from the console in Azure, but when executing it in the built process with powershell I can't access the wwwroot directory...

Comment: @BeatzCraft Do you mean you don't have enough permission? What can you do?

Comment: No, when I cd the powershell to the wwwroot folder in the VSTS Built it always states that it can't find the directory. cd D:\home\site\wwwroot Should work or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @BeatzCraft How do you specify the command? [command1] & [command2] for command line, [command1];[command2] for PowerShell. For example: cd D:\home\site\wwwroot & dir

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean with that. I add a task Azure PowerShell to the end of the build. And I use the Inline Script option and just type in: cd D:\home\site\wwwroot
If I would make it to the wwwroot directory in the powershell I could then run my composer install and php artisan commands.
But I get the error: ##[error]Cannot find path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot' because it does not exist.

Comment: @BeatzCraft You can't run that command in Azure PowerShell task, you need to call Kudu API. Refer to that thread to call Kudu API.

Comment: I have already read the thread and the documentation of the API, but it seems to me, that it only can Delete/read/update files and can't execute commands in the command line. 
Isn't it possible to just cd to the wwwroot from the Azure PowerShell in a task?

Comment: @BeatzCraft You can't to do it through Azure PowerShell task. There is Command API `POST /api/command`, check the [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API)