# How to access Kudu in Azure using power shell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, kudu

I am trying to access Kudu through power shell script. Link looks like: `https://adc-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net`. I need to copy `war` file located in `D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\webapps` location in above link.

Currently I am deploying the `war` file using VSTS by adding FTP task. But before deploying the latest `war` I would like to take backup of the old `war` in some location in Azure Kudu location say like: `D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\apache-tomcat-8.0.33` (root folder to the `war` location). So after that I can remove the `war` and deploy the latest `war` file in Kudu.

How to do this? I mean how to access kudu using power shell script. Please suggest me.

Comment: Thats a before DevOps era practice. Use a deployment slot instead, publish to staging, test and swap staging to Prod. If stuff no longer looks right just swap back.

Comment: Hi Peter, Could you please explain with the task names in VSTS as I am not understanding the above answer which you have given.Kindly,share me the steps how to access kudu through VSTS and take war backup (copy into another folder in kudu).Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this thread below to know how to call Kudu API through Azure PowerShell in VSTS build/release:

[Remove files and foldes on Azure before a new deploy from VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801618/remove-files-and-foldes-on-azure-before-a-new-deploy-from-vsts/43839007)

Regarding copy file through Kudu, you can use Command Kudu API (Post /api/command):

[Kudu REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API)

Update:

Simple sample to call Command through Kudu API:

```
  function RunCommand($dir,$command,$resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null){
        $kuduApiAuthorisationToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
        $kuduApiUrl="https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"
        $Body = 
          @{
          "command"=$command;
           "dir"=$dir
           } 
        $bodyContent=@($Body) | ConvertTo-Json
        Write-Host $bodyContent
         Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
                            -Headers @{"Authorization"=$kuduApiAuthorisationToken;"If-Match"="*"} `
                            -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $bodyContent
    }


RunCommand "site\wwwroot\bin\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\webapps" "copy xx.war ..\xx.war /y" "[resource group]" "[web app]"
```

Comment: Thanks MSFT.But can you please provide the exact script so that I can implement in my project.Just I need to copy war file from located in kudu ( https://adc-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net) under D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\webapps location into D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\apache-tomcat-8.0.33 this location and remove the war file from D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\webapps this location.After that I can deploy new war from VSTS using ftp.so how to write the script.Kindly provide the exact script as I am not understanding your links to my level.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN I updated my answer, for other code, just refer to the thread that I provide.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN I solved this issue with Kudu api [What is the best way to stop triggered web jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027845/what-is-the-best-way-to-stop-triggered-web-jobs), do you solve this issue with Kudu API too?

Comment: I didn't use this as I have found other way.I will let you know in future if I need any change or issues in this if I use this script.By the way I am accepting your answer.Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 3):

To access Kudu API, get your WebApp:

```
$app = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "your RG" -Name "your App"
```

Then get publishing credentials for the app:

```
$resourceName = "$($app.Name)/publishingcredentials";
$resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config";
$publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzResourceAction `
        -ResourceGroupName $app.ResourceGroup `
        -ResourceType $resourceType `
        -ResourceName $resourceName `
        -Action list `
        -ApiVersion $apiVersion `
        -Force;
```

Format the username/password suitable for a HTTP-request:

```
$user = $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName;
$pass = $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword;
$creds = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("${user}:${pass}")));
```

Finally, you can access the Kudu API:

```
$header = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $creds"
};
$kuduApiBaseUrl = "https://$($app.Name).scm.azurewebsites.net";
```

Example, check if extension is installed:

```
$extensionName = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.SiteExtension";
$kuduApiUrl = "$kuduApiBaseUrl/api/siteextensions/$extensionName";
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $kuduApiUrl -Headers $header;
```

Example, get list of available extensions:

```
$kuduApiUrl = "$kuduApiBaseUrl/api/extensionfeed";
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $kuduApiUrl -Headers $header;
```

Example, install an extension:

```
$kuduApiUrl = "$kuduApiBaseUrl/api/siteextensions";
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Put' -Uri $kuduApiUrl -Headers $header;
```

API-details are at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API

Also deployment slots can be accessed. App config needs to be retrieved for the slot and a minor modification of the base URL is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to access kudu apis from powershell -

```
 //function to Get webapp's publishing credentials    
    function Get-AzWebAppPublishingCredentials($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null) {
            if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($slotName) -or $slotName.ToLower() -eq "production") {
                $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
                $resourceName = "$webAppName/publishingcredentials"
            }
            else {
                $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config"
                $resourceName = "$webAppName/$slotName/publishingcredentials"
            }
            $publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
            return $publishingCredentials
    }

 //function to get authorization header from publishing credentials
     function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null) {
            $publishingCredentials = Get-AzWebAppPublishingCredentials $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
            $ret = @{ }
            $ret.header = ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
            $ret.url = $publishingCredentials.Properties.scmUri
            return $ret
        }

 //function to call kudu api e.g. to get a file from webapp
    function Get-FileFromWebApp($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = "", $kuduPath) {
        $KuduAuth = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
        $kuduApiAuthorisationToken = $KuduAuth.header
        $kuduApiUrl = $KuduAuth.url + "/api/vfs/$kuduPath"

        Write-Host " Downloading File from WebApp. Source: '$kuduApiUrl'." -ForegroundColor DarkGray
        $tmpPath = "$($env:TEMP)\$([guid]::NewGuid()).json"
        $null = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
            -Headers @{"Authorization" = $kuduApiAuthorisationToken; "If-Match" = "*" } `
            -Method GET `
            -ContentType "application/json" `
            -OutFile $tmpPath
        $ret = (Get-Content $tmpPath) | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
        Remove-Item $tmpPath -Force
        return $ret
    }
```