# dotnet core 2.0 webjob deployment - VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to deploy my webjob ( `dotnet core 2.0 commandline application` ) through `'release'` defination.  My `drop` folder contains webjob named 'MyWebjob.zip'.  I want to copy this to my webapps below directory where all tasks exists

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous>
```

Below is snap of of my existing `release` defination

[image]

Can anyone tell which copy job is suitable to copy contents from `drop` folder to '`wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous`' direcotry?

Or is there any easy way to deploy webjob ( dotnet core 2.0 ) using VSTS?

Note: I can't use FTP for some reason as 'Continuous Integration' is enabled for our project.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t use these tasks to deploy webjob.

If you remain the folder structure (`App_Data\jobs\continuous`) in `MyWebjob.zip` file, you can deploy it to azure web app through [Azure App Service Deploy](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment/README.md) task (App type: `Web App`; App Service name:`[your app service]`; Package or folder:`[that zip file]`; Check `Publish using Web Deploy` option).

Otherwise, I recommend that you can do it through **Extract files** and **Copy files** to organize the folder structure, then deploy through **Azure App Service Deploy task** (Package or folder:`[App_Data parent folder]`; Uncheck Publish using Web Deploy option).

You also can upload files through [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) (Extract zip file through Extract files task first)

There are some threads that can help you to call Kudu API in VSTS.

[Remove files and foldes on Azure before a new deploy from VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801618/remove-files-and-foldes-on-azure-before-a-new-deploy-from-vsts/43839007#43839007)

[How to access Kudu in Azure using power shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885075/how-to-access-kudu-in-azure-using-power-shell-script)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom target to your worker .csproj file.

```
  <Target Name="UpdateWebJobsPublishDir" BeforeTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PublishDir>$(PublishDir)App_Data/jobs/continuous/$(ProjectName)/</PublishDir>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

The above vill update the output dir before it is publised. In VSTS/Azure DevOps you just deploy you project as normal webapp it will be put in the right folder.