# How to copy files from production to staging slot before swapping in azure piplines

Tags: azure-pipelines, swap

We have a website that has an upload functionality for the CMS. When we do a release, the Azure pipeline we configured, deploys that release to the staging slot and then swaps staging and production. However any uploaded files are now on staging and not on production. I suppose uploading to a CDN would solve this but that is at the moment not an option. So i thought maybe i can download that folder to the staging slot before swapping. Is this possible and of so any ideas on how to do it?

EDIT:
This is the build pipeline:

```
trigger:
- development
- release

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  projects: '**/*.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'any cpu'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 2.2.401
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(projects)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(build.sourcesDirectory)\nuget.config'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-incremental'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

This is the release pipeline:
[image: Release Pipeline]

Basically after the release to the acceptance slot someone can approve the release for deployment on the production slot via staging. Once approved the following steps are done.

Azure App Service deploy using a webdeploy with these custom settings:
[image: Azure App Service deploy here]

And then swap staging and production slot using Azure App Service Manage using default options

So i want to download the uploaded files folder from the production slot and upload it to the same folder on the staging slot

EDIT 2, this is my script so far.

```
    param(
        [string]$resourceGroupName,
        [string]$webAppName,
        [string]$appPath="wwwroot",
        [string]$slotName="staging", 
        [string]$kuduPath,
        [string]$localPath,
        [bool]$recursive=$true
    )
    function Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingCredentials($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null) {
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($slotName)) {
            $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
            $resourceName = "$webAppName/publishingcredentials"
        }
        else {
            $resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config"
            $resourceName = "$webAppName/$slotName/publishingcredentials"
        }
        $publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
        Write-Host $publishingCredentials   
        return $publishingCredentials
    }
    function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotName = $null) {
        $publishingCredentials = Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingCredentials $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
        Write-Host $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName
        return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
    }
    function Get-ApiUrl($webAppName, $appPath, $slotName, $kuduPath, $recursive, $api = "vfs") {
        if ($recursive -eq $true) {
            if (-not ($kuduPath.endswith("recursive=true"))) {
               if (-not ($kuduPath.endswith("/"))) {
                  $kuduPath += "/"
               }
               $kuduPath += "?recursive=true"
            }
        }
        if ($slotName -eq "") {
            $kuduApiUrl = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/$api/site/$appPath/$kuduPath"
        }
        else {
            $kuduApiUrl = "https://$webAppName`-$slotName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/$api/site/$appPath/$kuduPath"
        }
        Write-Host $kuduApiUrl
        return $kuduApiUrl
    }
    function Get-KuduZipFile($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $appPath, $slotName, $kuduPath, $recursive, $localPath) {
        $kuduApiAuthorisationToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
        $kuduApiUrl = Get-ApiUrl $webAppName, $appPath, $slotName, $kuduPath, $recursive, "zip"
        try
        {
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
                            -Headers @{"Authorization"=$kuduApiAuthorisationToken;"If-Match"="*"} `
                            -Method GET `
                            -OutFile $localPath `
                            -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
        } catch {
            Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
            Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
            if (-not ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ -eq 404)) {
                throw $PSItem
            }
        }    
    }
    function Put-KuduZipFile($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $appPath, $slotName, $kuduPath, $recursive, $localPath){
        $kuduApiAuthorisationToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotName
        $kuduApiUrl = Get-ApiUrl $webAppName $appPath $slotName $kuduPath $recursive "zip"
        try
        {
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
                            -Headers @{"Authorization"=$kuduApiAuthorisationToken;"If-Match"="*"} `
                            -Method PUT `
                            -InFile $localPath `
                            -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
        } catch {
            Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
            Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
            if (-not ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ -eq 404)) {
                throw $PSItem
            }
        }    
    }

    Write-Host "resourceGroupName: $resourceGroupName"
    Write-Host "webAppName: $webAppName"
    Write-Host "appPath: $appPath"
    Write-Host "slotName: $slotName"
    Write-Host "kuduPath: $kuduPath"
    Write-Host "localPath: $localPath"
    Write-Host "recursive: $recursive"

    Get-KuduZipFile $resourceGroupName $webAppName $appPath "" $kuduPath $recursive $localPath
    Put-KuduZipFile $resourceGroupName $webAppName $appPath $slotName $kuduPath $recursive $localPath
```

The output is (removed some sensitive parts):

```
resourceGroupName: resourceGroupName
webAppName: webAppName
appPath: wwwroot
slotName: staging
kuduPath: Downloads
localPath: d:\a\r1\a
recursive: True


https://webAppName wwwroot  Downloads True zip-.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site//
```

But if i try in a local shell i get the following

```
PS N:\> Get-ApiUrl "webAppName" "appPath" "staging" "kuduPath" $true "zip"
https://webAppName-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/appPath/kuduPath/?recursive=true
```

So i don't understand why in the pipline the result is wrong. I use the following task in the pipeline:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-InlinePowershell

Comment: Hi Peter, can you share some details about your pipeline? How do you configure the related tasks in your release?

Comment: Added the information about the pipeline. If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: I guess your order is a deploy task used to deploy the web app to staging slot, and then do swapping?  If so, you can consider adding one download task before the deploying task: one powershell task to [download the files](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/08/30/interacting-with-azure-web-apps-virtual-file-system-using-powershell-and-the-kudu-api/). After the folder is downloaded, you can add that folder into your deploy package and then deploy them together to staging slot. It's one possible way. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480155/10910450)?

Comment: Hmm that could work. I that kudu also has a zip api. That could make it easier. So i zip and download the folder in 1 command and upload and unzip in another command. I also see that there is an option to run a PS script on the target machine. That could save me the upload i think. But then i don't know how i unzip the folder.

Comment: What's the reason why you don't do something for all slot? (Add another stage to deploy app using same artifact)

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question. But the files i want top copy are not part of the deploy but are uploaded trough the website itself.

Comment: `But then i don't know how i unzip the folder.` You can unzip the zip file using PS script, many related topics online. Something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7) may help :)

Comment: I've added the script so far but i get an error and i can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I've put the details at the end of the question.

Comment: What's the real error you got? Maybe Azure Powershell task is more suitable for you? Check if [starian's another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46903940/10910450) issue helps.

Comment: The error is that $kuduApiUrl is not a valid url. That's because the url that is returned from Get-ApiUrl is wrong. I copied that function into a local shell and that returns a correct url. The inline task returns:  ```"https://webAppName wwwroot  Downloads True zip-.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site//"```  and locally i get  ```"https://webAppName-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/appPath/kuduPath/?recursive=true"```  So i think there may be something wrong with that inline powershell task. But preferably i'd like to use the inline task and not add this script to the repository.

Comment: I tried the built in azure powershell task and i get the following error:   ##[error]At D:\a\_temp\515449d6-b78c-48e2-870c-5154b242202e.ps1:39 char:22  
+     [string]$appPath="wwwroot",    
+                      ~~~~~~~~~  
The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept   
assignments, such as a variable or a property.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidLeftHandSide

Comment: Copying from production to another slot is currently broken: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/524000/azure-webapp-copy-production-slot-into-staging-slo.html