# How to replace files from one folder to another folder in azure web app kudu site using the script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

**Context**:

1. Deploying the .NET Core Web app through Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipelines
2. After Release Pipeline, I need to replace files from one folder to another folder in the Kudu Site.

For example, source path is `C:\home\License\*.*` and the destination path is `C:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\License\`.

**Release Pipeline**:

[image]

**Error**:

```
2024-01-03T12:09:23.8052852Z ##[section]Starting: Command Line Script
2024-01-03T12:09:23.8178628Z ==============================================================================
2024-01-03T12:09:23.8178789Z Task         : Command line
2024-01-03T12:09:23.8178893Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2024-01-03T12:09:23.8179040Z Version      : 2.231.1
2024-01-03T12:09:23.8179117Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2024-01-03T12:09:23.8179229Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2024-01-03T12:09:23.8179378Z ==============================================================================
2024-01-03T12:09:24.9976497Z Generating script.
2024-01-03T12:09:25.0087762Z Script contents: shell
2024-01-03T12:09:25.0096759Z az webapp copy --resource-group Practice-RG --name basicdotnetwebapp --src-path C:\home\License\*.* --dest-path C:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\License\
2024-01-03T12:09:25.0441739Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2024-01-03T12:09:25.0730789Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\<guid>.cmd""
2024-01-03T12:10:37.0437891Z ERROR: 'copy' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.
2024-01-03T12:10:37.0439572Z 
2024-01-03T12:10:37.0440014Z Examples from AI knowledge base:
2024-01-03T12:10:37.0440430Z https://aka.ms/cli_ref
2024-01-03T12:10:37.0440810Z Read more about the command in reference docs
2024-01-03T12:10:39.0472120Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '2'.
2024-01-03T12:10:39.1911632Z ##[section]Finishing: Command Line Script
```

Comment: You need to make use of Kudu Rest API and call execute your command -https://www.appsloveworld.com/azure-devops/29/how-to-access-kudu-in-azure-using-power-shell-script?expand_article=1

Comment: Refer here too -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885075/how-to-access-kudu-in-azure-using-power-shell-script

Comment: its taking time to check this method. If you have tried previously, could you please provide the solution

Comment: I have tried this code, But you need to tweak it according to your requirement

Comment: $userName = "`$siliconwebapp098"  
# Provide Password from WebDeploy Publish Profile  
$password = "xxxxxxx9reT0tX"  
# Encode username and password to base64 string  
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $userName, $password)))  
# Construct command API Body. DOS command to create a folder called TempLogsForDebugging  
$bodyToPOST = @{  
command = "md TempLogsForDebugging"
                 dir = "D:\home\site\wwwroot"  
}

Comment: # Splat all parameters together in $param  
$param = @{  
            # command REST API url  
            Uri = "https://siliconwebapp098.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"  
            Headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  
            UserAgent = "powershell/1.0"  
            Method = "POST"  
            Body = (ConvertTo-Json $bodyToPOST)  
            ContentType = "application/json"  
}  
# Invoke REST call  
Invoke-RestMethod @param

Comment: Download the Publish profile and fetch username and password from here - https://i.imgur.com/o6gdxig.png

Comment: Make sure the Basic Authentication in Web app configuration > General settings is set to ON

Comment: Yes @SiddheshDesai, I'm trying to get username, password with the code given in comments section on this SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77756198/22054564)

Comment: Try this command - https://i.imgur.com/5EsahpJ.png Get-AzureRMWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName AI_ML-Resources -Name qnamkaertest

Comment: I know that command but my question how to fetch username and password to a variable

Comment: This just got answered -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77756198/invalidoperation-cannot-index-into-a-null-array-while-fetching-the-value-from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of `Kudu Rest API via Powershell` to access and replace a file in Kudu:-

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885075/how-to-access-kudu-in-azure-using-power-shell-script)

***My Azure DevOps Release pipeline:-
Powershell Code:-***

```
$userName = "`$siliconwebapp098"  
# Provide Password from WebDeploy Publish Profile  
$password = "xxxxxxx9reT0tX"  
# Encode username and password to base64 string  
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $userName, $password)))  
# Construct command API Body. DOS command to create a folder called TempLogsForDebugging  
$bodyToPOST = @{  
command = "md TempLogsForDebugging"
                 dir = "D:\home\site\wwwroot"  
}  
# Splat all parameters together in $param  
$param = @{  
            # command REST API url  
            Uri = "https://siliconwebapp098.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"  
            Headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  
            UserAgent = "powershell/1.0"  
            Method = "POST"  
            Body = (ConvertTo-Json $bodyToPOST)  
            ContentType = "application/json"  
}  
# Invoke REST call  
Invoke-RestMethod @param
```

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

**One more alternative is to use `Kudu Tasks Upload`**

[image]

***And specify your destination path accordingly:-***

[image]

In order to get Publish profile via powershell and get it into a variable refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77756198/invalidoperation-cannot-index-into-a-null-array-while-fetching-the-value-from) by Jahnavi

Comment: Your answer is helpful and can be acceptable but please confirm this - I think the powershell script - I mean the command inside the script, you written is some other functionality not the replacing of files. - Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, My code just implements kudu rest api functionality. To replace files, You need to implement something like this- # PowerShell script to copy files from one folder to another in Azure App Service using Kudu API

# Authenticate to the Azure App Service using Basic Authentication
$userName = "siliconwebapp098"  # Replace with your username
$password = "xxxxxxx9reT0tX"    # Replace with your password

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $userName, $password)))

Comment: $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $userName, $password)))

# Construct the command to copy files via Kudu API
$sourcePath = "D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\License"  # Source path
$destinationPath = "D:\home\site\wwwroot\License"      # Destination path

$bodyToPOST = @{
    command = "xcopy"
    dir = $sourcePath
    destination = $destinationPath
}

Comment: # Splat all parameters together in $param
$param = @{
    Uri = "https://siliconwebapp098.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"
    Headers = @{
        Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)
    }
    UserAgent = "powershell/1.0"
    Method = "POST"
    Body = (ConvertTo-Json $bodyToPOST)
    ContentType = "application/json"
}

# Invoke REST call to execute the command via Kudu API
Invoke-RestMethod @param

Comment: Refer this - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and valuable time. Can I also get a upvote to my question if possible.