# InvalidOperation: Cannot index into a null array - while fetching the value from the array in Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-appservice

I'm trying to fetch the username and password from the publishing profile of the azure web app with the Azure PowerShell code, but i'm getting the error in username fetching line"

**Code**:

```
$WebApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "Practice-RG" -Name "testwebapp7298"
$publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $WebApp
# Create Base64 authorization header
$username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
$password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
```

**Result**:

```
PS /home/sheethal> $WebApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "Practice-RG" -Name "testwebapp7298"
PS /home/sheethal> $publishingProfile = Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $WebApp
PS /home/sheethal> # Create Base64 authorization header
PS /home/sheethal> $username = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName
InvalidOperation: Cannot index into a null array.
PS /home/sheethal> $password = $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userPWD
InvalidOperation: Cannot index into a null array.
PS /home/sheethal> $publishingProfile.publishData.publishProfile[0].userName           
InvalidOperation: Cannot index into a null array.
PS /home/sheethal>
```

[image]

Could anyone correct where I did mistake in the code?

Comment: Instead of writing multiple lines of code, you can use [`az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deployment-list-publishing-profiles) to fetch the usernames and passwords easily as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/e3j8jUq.png). @The Massacre

Comment: How to save the username and password in variables after fetching using above command?

Comment: `$profile` is a variable only. I saved in `$profile` variable. It means you are simply saving it in `$profile` variable itself. @The Massacre

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/zdvOg8D.png - How to fetch username and password

Comment: `az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name <webapp> --resource-group xxxx --query '[].userName' -o tsv` You need to use this. @The Massacre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing multiple lines of code with `Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile`command, you can use
[`az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deployment-list-publishing-profiles) to fetch the usernames and passwords from the publishing profile easily.

```bash
$userNames=az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name newjan --resource-group xxxx --query '[].userName' -o tsv
$userNames
$Passwords=az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name newjan --resource-group xxxx --query '[].userPWD' -o tsv
$Passwords
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Instead of executing the same command for username once and password once with the query parameter, can we get the username and password in one command line - one variable to store both usernames and passwords?

Comment: Or Please Wait @Jahnavi, I'll raise the new request for this requirement instead of extending to multiple comments

Comment: Yes it can be done in a single attempt as well. Refer the command structure `$Profile=az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name <webapp> --resource-group xxxx --query '[].{UserName: userName, Password: userPWD}' -o tsv ` as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/QwztBtL.png). @TheMassacre

Comment: Oh Apologies. could you please respond in the question raised few moments ago. - https://stackoverflow.com/q/77756540/22054564

Comment: Updated. You can check it. @TheMassacre