# Can we get the username and password in single variable array from the azure cli command given

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-appservice

This is Continuity to or requirement, from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77756198/22054564).

Instead of running the command for usernames once and passwords once, can't we run the below command to store both username and password in same array variable and fetch.

```bash
$userNames=az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name newjan --resource-group xxxx --query '[].userName' -o tsv
$userNames
$Passwords=az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name newjan --resource-group xxxx --query '[].userPWD' -o tsv
$Passwords
```

This code snippets given by the user [Jahnavi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19785512/jahnavi)

**Requirement**:

I need the same command to store both usernames and passwords in the same variable array but I'm getting below errors when I tried:

```bash
 $userCreds=az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name newjan --resource-group xxxx --query '[].userName, [].userPWD' -o tsv
ERROR: argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: '[].userName, [].userPWD'
To learn more about --query, please visit: 'https://docs.microsoft.com/cli/azure/query-azure-cli'
```

```bash
$userCreds=az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name newjan --resource-group xxxx --query '[].userName', '[].userPWD' -o tsv
ERROR: argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: "'[].userName',"
To learn more about --query, please visit: 'https://docs.microsoft.com/cli/azure/query-azure-cli'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77756429/19785512) worked by me, it can be done in a single attempt with the command `az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles` as shown below.

```bash
$Profile=az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name <webapp> --resource-group xxxx --query '[].{UserName: userName, Password: userPWD}' -o tsv
$Profile
```

***Output:***

[image]