# How to remove files from the kudu site folder using command in the Azure devops release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

**Context**: After deployment, remove the files from the specific folder in the Kudu Site Console.

[image]

I have used a script syntax given in my former [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77751991/how-to-replace-files-from-one-folder-to-another-folder-in-azure-web-app-kudu-sit) but the command is different here.

I tried with the following commands but didn't worked:

```
del /Q "C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\*"
```

```
Remove-Item -Path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\*' -force
```

**Error**: `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\*'`.

**Total Script**:

```
$WebApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "AppServPlan-RG" -Name "testwebapp1013"
$publishingProfile = [xml](Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $WebApp)
# Create Base64 authorization header
$Username = (Select-Xml -Xml $PublishingProfile -XPath "//publishData/publishProfile[contains(@profileName,'Web Deploy')]/@userName").Node.Value
$Password = (Select-Xml -Xml $PublishingProfile -XPath "//publishData/publishProfile[contains(@profileName,'Web Deploy')]/@userPWD").Node.Value
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $Username,$Password)))


$bodyToPOST = @{  
command = del /Q "C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\*" | XCOPY C:\home\License\*.* C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\
                 dir = "C:\home\"  
}  
# Splat all parameters together in $param  
$param = @{  
            # command REST API url  
            Uri = "https://testwebapp1013.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"  
            Headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  
            UserAgent = "powershell/1.0"  
            Method = "POST"  
            Body = (ConvertTo-Json $bodyToPOST)  
            ContentType = "application/json"  
}  
# Invoke REST call  
Invoke-RestMethod @param
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using your sample:

[image]

To Solve this issue, you can use the following sample:

```
$WebApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "AppServPlan-RG" -Name "testwebapp1013"
$publishingProfile = [xml](Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -WebApp $WebApp)
# Create Base64 authorization header
$Username = (Select-Xml -Xml $PublishingProfile -XPath "//publishData/publishProfile[contains(@profileName,'Web Deploy')]/@userName").Node.Value
$Password = (Select-Xml -Xml $PublishingProfile -XPath "//publishData/publishProfile[contains(@profileName,'Web Deploy')]/@userPWD").Node.Value
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $Username,$Password)))


$bodyToPOST = @{  
command = "del /Q C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\* | XCOPY C:\home\License\*.* C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\"
                 dir = "C:\home\"  
}  
# Splat all parameters together in $param  
$param = @{  
            # command REST API url  
            Uri = "https://testwebapp1013.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/command"  
            Headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  
            UserAgent = "powershell/1.0"  
            Method = "POST"  
            Body = (ConvertTo-Json $bodyToPOST)  
            ContentType = "application/json"  
}  
# Invoke REST call  
Invoke-RestMethod @param
```

You need to add double quotes to the entire command.

From

```
command = del /Q "C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\*" | XCOPY C:\home\License\*.* C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\
```

To

```
command = "del /Q C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\* | XCOPY C:\home\License\*.* C:\home\site\wwwroot\License\"
```

**Result sample:**

[image]

Comment: @TheMassacre sure. Glad to know that it can work for you