# VSTS Web Deploy Arguments produce error

Tags: angularjs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, devops

I'm deploying an Angular JS app using web deploy on VSTS. I'm also trying to target a specific path on the Azure app service, specifically `/home/site/` to deploy the project files.

If not specified, the app will just deploy to `/home/site/wwwroot/`

To target this specific path, I'm using arguments, here is the argument:

```
-verb:sync -source:contentPath="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Atlas-CI-Develop/atlas-ui/*.zip" -dest:contentPath="D:\home\site\PS.UI"
```

Here's the not so nice error i'm getting:

```
2017-12-18T20:45:27.4283104Z ##[error]Error: Argument '-verb' may only be specified once.
```

I don't know anywhere else in my pipeline i'm using the attribute `verb`, `source` or `dest`. No other deployment uses web deploy arguments other than the UI.

I have absolutely no idea where to start debugging this issue and any help or insight is tremendously appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the `-verb` parameter is included in the code of build/release task, so you can’t specify it again. For example, if the build/release task uses [webdeployment-common/msdeployutility](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/Common/webdeployment-common/msdeployutility.ts) (e.g. **Azure App Service deploy** task), then the `-verb:sync` parameter will be included.

Also, `-source` and `-dest` parameters will be specified in the code of build/release task, you just need to specify them in the task UI, for example: **Azure App Service Deploy** task (App Service name: xxx; Package or folder: xxx)

Regarding the target path, you can add new virtual directory to Azure app service (Application settings=> Virtual applications and directories), then specify **Virtual application** in **Azure App Service Deploy** task)

Comment: I'm confused because if it's already included in the Azure App Service Deploy, why does it give me the option to add arguments to a web deploy? Secondly, I only see a place to add the source under the `Package or Folder` field but not the destination. If you're referring to virtual application location, I'm trying to avoid deploying it as a virtual application and editing the Virtual applications and directories in the app service settings. I hope that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Mihado There are additional arguments for web deploy, check [Web Deploy Operation Settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089(v=ws.10).aspx). Regarding the virtual application location, you can change default setting of virtual application (by default, it deploy to the `/` virtual application location, as far as I know, you can't change the location through Azure App Service Deploy task. On the other hand, you can upload web app files through Kudu api.

Comment: This thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801618/remove-files-and-foldes-on-azure-before-a-new-deploy-from-vsts/43839007#43839007